# Error in dynamic execute with local variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the error :

> Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'

for the following execute statement. I'm a little confused with this, after reading several posts on the website, 
I came to understand that I would need to pass `@val` as a variable since `exec` will execute the command as-is.

```
declare @val varchar(max); 
declare @query nvarchar(max);

set @query = 'set @val = (select ' + @cols + ' from temp where loan_number = ''72'')'
exec sp_executesql @query, '@val varchar(max) output', @val output
```

Conversely, if I executed the `exec` as a non-dynamic query as just `exec(@query)`, I get the error
`Must declare the scalar variable "@val".`

Comment: How do you set the value of a **scalar** variable to be the result of a dataset? It would be like doing `SET @variable = (SELECT * FROM sys.tables);`. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: Should the output of the query be a `1x1` table since I have a where clause (no duplicates). I'm trying to dynamically extract the value in my given column (which can change) into the variable `@val` and use that variable in an `if` comparison statement (not shown here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***IF*** the statement *"Should the output of the query be a 1x1 table since I"* is true, then you need to use a `SELECT` to set the value:

```
DECLARE @val varchar(MAX); 
DECALRE @query nvarchar(MAX);

SET @query = N'SELECT @val = ' + QUOTENAME(@cols) + N' FROM temp WHERE loan_number = ''72'');';
EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@val varchar(MAX) OUTPUT', @val OUTPUT;
```

The fact that you have a variable called `@cols` *implies* that the variable will hold the names of many columns, not one.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: `Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.` Even after hard coding a specific column name for `@cols` I get the same error.

Comment: @Josh, then specify a nvarchar literal for the `@params` paramter: `N'@val varchar(MAX) OUTPUT'`

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks. What does the `N` mean here? Secondly, I have a conceptual question - I am actually not executing a stored procedure using the `exec` rather just some random query - so how does `exec` still work in this case

Comment: @Josh, the `N` prefix denotes a Unicode string literal. `sp_executesql` requires strongly typed paramter values and won't implictly convert the varchar literal to nvarchar. The `sp_executesql` system proc can execute any batch of sql statements with or without parameters. There would be no need to use it to execute a single proc since you could call it using `EXEC` directly.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman , must have missed that one out when I copied and corrected the OP's code.